# How to left join when there are repeating left table observations?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with two very large data sets and am attempting to perform a left join.

Data frame 1 :

```
Name   MonthId     WeekId  Day
Jim    January       1      1
Mike   January       1      1
Eric   January       1      1
Jim    February      2      1
Mike   February      2      1
Eric   February      2      1
Jim    February      2      2
Mike   February      2      2
Eric   February      2      2
Jim    March         1      1
Mike   March         1      1
Eric   March         1      1
```

Data Frame 2:

```
Name   MonthId     WeekId    Score
Jim    January       1         91
Mike   January       1         92
Eric   January       1         85
Jim    February      2         87  
Mike   February      2         95
Eric   February      2         96
Jim    March         1         81
Mike   March         1         92
Eric   March         1         87
```

I would like the merged data set to look like this:

```
Name   MonthId     WeekId    Day     Score
Jim    January       1        1      91
Mike   January       1        1      92
Eric   January       1        1      85
Jim    February      2        1      87  
Mike   February      2        1      95
Eric   February      2        1      96
Jim    February      2        2      87  
Mike   February      2        2      95
Eric   February      2        2      96
Jim    March         1        1      81
Mike   March         1        1      92
Eric   March         1        1      87
```

As you can see the complicating factor is that there is no `Day` column in table two. If there are multiple different days for a given week within the first table, I would just like to match them all with whatever is there for that month/week in the second table. Is this possible? I have already tried this code but it is not cooperating (and generating a lot of NAs.

```
datfinal <- merge(x = dat1, y = dat2, by = "MonthId", "WeekId", "Name", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: You are missing the `c()` around your `by` columns. Change to `by = c("MonthId", "WeekId", "Name")`. The missing `Day` column isn't an issue.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks so much! Would you like to post this as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are missing the `c()` around your `by` columns, so they are interpreted as different arguments. You can change to:

```
datfinal <- merge(x = dat1, y = dat2, by = c("MonthId", "WeekId", "Name"), all.x = TRUE)
```